# Handling generic classes that is instanciated at run-time based on database data

Tags: c#, database, generics, types

I have a problem with my generic classes and creating them at run-time, based on data that is located in a database. In the following I have tried to give a simple example of the problem, with a generic counter class that keep track of how often a value occur in a column.

The class `Counter` is the generic class, the class `Table` simulates a database table with two columns, and the `Wrapper` class contains the problem :)

Basically the wrapper class provides a DBMS independent interface to my databases and expose functionalists to the application. Note that I an aware of what data types my columns have, but how to i provide a generic access to my counter object?

```
public class Counter<T>
{
    private Dictionary<T, int> _counter = new Dictionary<T,int>();

    public Counter() {}

    public Counter(List<T> values) : this()
    {
        foreach (var item in values)
            this.Add(item);
    }

    public void Add(T key)
    {
        if (!this._counter.ContainsKey(key))
            this._counter[key] = 0;
        this._counter[key] += 1;
    }

    public int GetCount(T key)
    {
        return this._counter[key];
    }
}

public class Table
{
    public List<int> IDs { get; private set; }
    public List<String> Names { get; private set; }

    public Table()
    {
        this.IDs = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        this.Names = new List<string> { "a", "b", "a", "c", "d" };
    }
}

public class Wrapper
{
    private Table _table = new Table();

    public ... GetCounter(string columnName)
    {
        if (columnName == "id")
            return new Counter<..>(this._table.IDs);
        else if (columnName == "name")
            return new Counter<..>(this._table.Names);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the GetCounter method to a generic function:

```
public Counter<T> GetCounter<T>(string columnName)
{
    if (columnName == "id")
        return new Counter<T>(this._table.IDs);
    else if (columnName == "name")
        return new Counter<T>(this._table.Names);
}
```